# python - Give UTC time get Time in Japan using pytz

Tags: python, pytz

Here is UTC time:

```
now_utc = datetime.datetime.now(timezone('UTC'))
```

Here is the time zone of Tokyo:

```
 tz = Asia/Tokyo
```

So...using pytz how to I get the local time on Japan?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
now_utc.astimezone(timezone('Asia/Tokyo'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import pytz
import datetime

a = datetime.datetime.now() # UTC
b = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone('Asia/Tokyo')) # for Japan time zone
```

Output example

a:

```
datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 27, 9, 39, 48, 451388)
```

b:

```
datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 27, 18, 37, 28, 78739, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Tokyo' JST+9:00:00 STD>)
```